# Connecting to FTPS server from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftps

I have a PHP script running on my EC2 instance which uses cURL to connect to a remote FTPS server on port 990. When I run the script in local or in my other production server, the script runs without problems but from EC2 I only get the message

```
"Failed to connect to aaa.bbb.ccc port 990: Connection refused".
```

I checked inbound and outbound rules for the instance's security group, created new rules, allowed all traffic, tested different combinations, etc. I even created a new security group exclusively with rules for allowing inbound and outbound traffic, but it's not working.

I don't know if besides the security group rules there is something else I have to configure. I don't know what else can I check. Normally, when I wanted to access through SSH to my EC2 instance I only had to configure the inbound rule with my IP and that all, but with this I'm a bit lost.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: First test if you can hit other things on the Internet from that EC2 instance. Like can you `curl` google.com or something?

Comment: Yes, I was able to cURL the website https://bik.weblands.es (is on other of my servers) and echo the HTML contents I got. I wanted to to test if port 990 is open and discard outbound rules problem but I don't know how.

Comment: Just make sure you have a single outbound rule in the security group that allows all traffic on any port.

Comment: Does the "Connection refused" error come back immediately, or does it take some time (eg 10 seconds) before it fails? If immediate, then the network connection is fine and your request is simply being refused. If it takes a long time, this suggests that the network connection is not being established (most often due to Security Groups).

Comment: The error comes back inmediately.